# find all isometries that commute with this linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, isometry

as in the title given the application  $F(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-\frac{1}{2}x_1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x_2+\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2+\frac{\sqrt3}{6};-x_3)$

1)find all isometries of $\mathbb R^3$ that commute with F

2)find an isometry G of  $\mathbb R^3$ that commute with F and write its expression.

**my considerations:**

this kind of application reminds me a "-" rotation around z axes of $\pi/6$ , so a rotation of $-\pi/6$ is it right ?
but i don't have ideas on finding  **isometries**, I thought I could find another application G (not an isometry) just creating  $3*3$ matrix and imposing the standard condition $G*F=F*G$